# React Native: Why is shouldComponentUpdate being called when neither props nor state have changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-lifecycle, react-class-based-component

In my React Native app I have a PureComponent where I log whether props or state have changed each time `shouldComponentUpdate()` is called, like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props) === JSON.stringify(nextProps))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state) === JSON.stringify(nextState))
    return true
}
```

In one instance, this outputs `true` and `true`, meaning neither props nor state have changed. I thought that in order for `shouldComponentUpdate()` to get called, one of these has to change. What could cause it to get called when neither has changed?

Comment: How could `shouldComponentUpdate()` do its job (checking whether the compenent should be re-rendered or not) if it is not called every single time? The component will be re-rendered only if a prop or the state changed but, in order to detect the change, `shouldComponentUpdate()` needs to be called and evaluate them.